# "Cannot find symbol" error for java palindrome client program

Tags: java, compiler-errors, client, symbols, palindrome

I tried everything and looked through many forum posts but could not find the problem with my program. I'm trying to use the methods in the program in the client class and it keeps telling me it can't find it. If anyone could help me figure it out, that would be great. Here is the programs and the error:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Palindrome {

   private String palindrome;

 public Palindrome(){
 } // end constructor

public Palindrome(String newPalindrome){
       palindrome = newPalindrome;
 } // end Palindrome

 public static boolean isPalindrome(){

      String temp = "";
       boolean toBe = true; // Is a palindrome
boolean notToBe = false; // Is not a palindrome
        int low = 0; // First character
      int high = temp.length() - 1; // Last character

         while (low < high){
             if (temp.charAt(low) != temp.charAt(high))
                          return notToBe;

               low++;
                  high--;
            } // end while

  return toBe; 
 }// end isPalindrome

     public static String filter(){

String palindrome = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // Create a string builder


for (int i = 0; i < palindrome.length(); i++) { // Examine each char in the string to skip alphanumeric char
  if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(palindrome.charAt(i))) {
    stringBuilder.append(palindrome.charAt(i));
  } // end if
} // end for

// Return a new filtered string
return stringBuilder.toString();
} // end filter

 public String removeWhite(){

     String temp = "";

       temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s+","");

         return temp;
 } // end removeWhite

 public String lowerCase(){

           String temp = "";

           temp = temp.toLowerCase();

       return temp;
  } // end toLowerCase

 } // end the class
```

Here is the client code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class TestPalindrome {

public static void main(String args[]){


       Palindrome pal = new Palindrome("") ;

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                  
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");// Prompt the user to enter a string
  String temporary = (input.nextLine());
    String string = ("");

        temporary = pal;
        temporary.lowerCase();
        string.removeWhite();
        string.filter();
        string.isPalindrome();

        System.out.println(string);                    
   } // end main method

} // end the class
```

Error:

```
        TestPalindrome.java:30: error: incompatible types

        temporary = pal;
                    ^ 
        required: String

        found:    Palindrome
       TestPalindrome.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
         temporary.lowerCase();
                  ^
        symbol:   method lowerCase()
       location: variable temporary of type String
       TestPalindrome.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        string.removeWhite();
              ^
       symbol:   method removeWhite()
       location: variable string of type String
       TestPalindrome.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        string.filter();
              ^
       symbol:   method filter()
       location: variable string of type String
       TestPalindrome.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        string.isPalindrome();
              ^
        symbol:   method isPalindrome()
        location: variable string of type String
        5 errors
```

Comment: You can not assign a instance of `Palindrome` to `String`.

Comment: And once you realize that, you'll also know that all those methods called on `temporary` are not valid as its not a `Palindrome` object. You need to either change the type of `temporary` to `Palindrome` or call those methods on `pal` and not `temporary`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed few things to make this work !

```
> public class Palindrome {
    private String palindrome;

    public Palindrome() {
    } // end constructor

    public Palindrome(String newPalindrome) {
        palindrome = newPalindrome;
    } // end Palindrome

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {

    String temp = string;
        boolean toBe = true; // Is a palindrome
        boolean notToBe = false; // Is not a palindrome
        int low = 0; // First character
        int high = temp.length() - 1; // Last character


        while (low < high) {
            if (temp.charAt(low) != temp.charAt(high))
                return notToBe;

            low++;
            high--;
        } // end while
        return toBe;
    }// end isPalindrome

    public static String filter(String string) {

        String palindrome = string;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // Create a string
                                                            // builder

        for (int i = 0; i < palindrome.length(); i++) { // Examine each char in
                                                        // the string to skip
                                                        // alphanumeric char
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(palindrome.charAt(i))) {
                stringBuilder.append(palindrome.charAt(i));
            } // end if
        } // end for

        // Return a new filtered string
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } // end filter

    public String removeWhite(String string) {

        String temp = string;

        temp = temp.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        return temp;
    } // end removeWhite

    public String lowerCase(String string) {

        String temp = string;

        temp = temp.toLowerCase();

        return temp;
    } // end toLowerCase

} // end the class
```

And the testpalindrome code is below ....

```
>package san.org.tst1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPalindrome {
    public static void main(String args[]){


           Palindrome pal = new Palindrome("") ;

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                  
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");// Prompt the user to enter a string
      String temporary = (input.nextLine());
        String string = ("");


          //  temporary.toLowerCase();
            String testIsLowercase = pal.lowerCase(string);
            String removeWhitetest = pal.removeWhite(string);
            String filter = pal.filter(string);
            boolean testIspalindrome =  pal.isPalindrome(string);

            System.out.println(" removing lowercase : " + testIsLowercase);  
            System.out.println(" removing removeWhite : " + removeWhitetest);                
            System.out.println(" removing Filter : " + filter);         
            System.out.println("Is Palindrome : " + testIspalindrome);                    



       } // end main method

    } // end the class
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know what version of java that you are using, but there is no `String.lowerCase()` method.

Also a `Palindrome` `can not be cast` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a `Palindrome` object to a `String`, which doesn't make sense. Note that you have declared `string` as a `String`, so you can't call the methods `lowerCase()` or `filter()` because they are defined only for `Palindrome` objects. Maybe you want to assign the result of `removeWhite()` or `lowerCase()` to that `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Palindrome in this case it not directly convertible to String. You need to override the `toString` method and call that on Palindrome to make it into a String.

You can call the `trim` and `toLowerCase` functions on the string directly. Those functions are bound to the `Palindrome` class. `isPalindrome` should be made non-static. The `temp` or `palindrome` local variable in each of the functions should directly modify the `palindrome` member variable.